# OmniThreadLibrary Overview

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, omnithreadlibrary

Is there a place where there is an introductory overview of the OmniThreadLibray for Delphi?

I have the current code installed in Delphi XE. The examples work.  I've been looking over the associated *The Delphi Geek* blog with usage examples. [Gabr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4997/gabr) admits the documentation does not exist. I would like to get a handle of the structure of the framework before diving into specific examples. I do have an understanding of the usage of TThread so I don't need go to a Threading 101 site.

The framework has shown to have a loyal following and I'd like to think I just haven't looked in the right place.

Comment: The examples at the blog is where to start. If you have a problem understanding one of the examples, then ask a specific question. Otherwise this question should attract *not a real question* close votes.

Comment: @David - I disagree. I'm asking a specific question about the existance of an overview of the framework. If it doesn't exist, even by a third party, so be it. If that's the case I think it can be a helpful signpost for others who are pointed towards the framework.

Comment: Right! Even if the answer would be a simple "no" in the moment, as the question stays here for longer, the answer might actually change in the future.

Comment: @Uwe I don't think anyone possibly be able to answer "no" with any authority. Non-existance answers are rather difficult.

Comment: +1 and favourite, so I get warned when some more documentation does appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the OmniThreadLibrary, [Primož Gabrijelčič](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4997/gabr),  is working on a book to document the library. It started off as a wiki and has been growing.

[OmniThreadLibrary Book Wiki](http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php)

The ebook: [Parallel Programming with the OmniThreadLibrary](http://leanpub.com/omnithreadlibrary)

As sections are completed in the Wiki they are added to the eBook. From Primož's [blog](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/06/parallel-programming-with.html):

> In accordance with the Lean Publishing Manifesto, Parallel Programming
>   with OmniThreadLibrary is published as it is written. When I’m happy
>   with a chapter (or even with a section, if it is important enough), I
>   click the Publish button on the LeanPub site and new, updated book is
>   available to all the readers

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no overview of the type you're talking about.  The closest there really is is the examples. They provide demonstrations of the things you can do with OTL, and you can study the code to see what they're doing and how it's implemented.  I don't think you'll find anything better than that, for the moment at least.

Comment: It looks like this will be the case for now. What I discovered is that I was able to generate modeling documentation in my Enterprise Edition that gives a useful snap shot of the the package that I can refer to as I work with the examples. Maybe this documentation can be provided with the package in the future.

Comment: @Rich: Sure, I'll be happy to push it to the repository and include in the distribution.

Comment: @gabr - The Zip archive of the files and structure as created by Delphi XE is ped file as created by Delphi XE is about 4.5MBs. It can be unzipped anywhere and appears to be usable. It might make sense to package it this way, or to simply give instruction on how to generate it. I don't know if Delphi Professional can create it, so that may factor into making it separate from the main download.

Comment: @Rich: Delphi Professional can't do this otherwise I'd be happy to do this myself. Just give me the URL and I'll create a separate download on the Google Code site.

Comment: I can set up a temporary FTP site tonight at home for you to grab it. How can I contact you via email with the information? Or should I examine the Google Code site to upload it.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the current answer. For the new release I've given Gabr a set of Delphi XE Enterprise's generated UML diagrams to be made available.  I think it it will be helpful in understanding the product.